# Fluid is not generated

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

Following few videos on youtube, I try to create a very simple fluid animation:

1. Creating a cube for domain
2. Creating a circle and change Fill Type to Triangle fan.
3. Placing circle inside the cube
4. In physics tab while circle selected creating Inflow fluid
5. In physics tab while cube is selected creating Domain fluid

Clicking on Bake button and as result nothing happens. I see progress bar working up to 100% without giving any error but there is no fluid simulation.
If I change circle to other type of geometry - it work. I want to use the circle to generate a water flow as it is coming from pipe.

I am using 2.78c version

Comment: The inflow needs to have some thickness. You could try using a very thin cylinder.

Comment: Thanks for reply. When I add thickness the container is generating fluid in shape and volume of inflow object and this is not what I want to achieve. I want to generate effect as water streaming from a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem. My fix was to make the pipe *after* I simulated the fluid. This works pretty realistically. Hope this works for you!